# buy nintendo eshop card in US for Canada

Tags: wii-u, nintendo-eshop

I don't see any nintendo eshop cards in Canada, which can be delivered online.

If I buy such card in US, will it work in Canada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from [this discussion](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/68741455) you can't use US eshop card if your console set to Canadian region. Although you could do the following:

> You have two options. You could format your 3ds and set the region to
>   US(you will lose all data in your SD, system memory, and will unlink
>   your NNID from your system excluding preinstalled games if you bought
>   a limited edition 3ds) or you could ditch your US eshop card and buy
>   the Canadian one.

Anyway I found where I can buy Canadian eshop card, so problem is solved.